# Not connecting to Android KSOAP Webservice

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2

I have a webservice on my `localhost` which has a simple method to connect to database and also return the name of cities in an array of strings.

Here is the link when I run my service:

```
http://localhost:1543/Service1.asmx
```

I'm trying to connect to this webservice via Android application,but I think I don't choose the `namespace` or `soapaction` and so forth correctly,So I receive the following exception.

**expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope (position:START_TAG @2:7 in java.io.InputStreamReader@41387778)**

Here is my android Code:

```
    public class ProvinceCityActivity extends Activity
{
    EditText txtProvince;
    Button btnResult;

    private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/GetCities";

    private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static String METHOD_NAME = "GetCities";

    private static String URL = "http://192.168.0.109:1543/Service1.asmx";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        txtProvince = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtProvince);
        btnResult = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnResult);
        btnResult.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
                request.addProperty("value", txtProvince.getText().toString());
                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                        SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                envelope.dotNet = true;


                try
                {
                    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(
                            URL);
                    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);


                    SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
                    if (result != null)
                    {
                        String[] strResult = (String[]) result.getProperty(0);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Cities: " + strResult[0], 6000).show();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            e.getMessage().toString(), 6000).show();
                }

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
05-15 05:10:07.651: D/dalvikvm(632): GC_CONCURRENT freed 101K, 78% free 462K/2048K, paused 1ms+1ms
05-15 05:10:07.661: D/dalvikvm(632): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
05-15 05:10:07.671: I/AndroidRuntime(632): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
05-15 05:10:08.252: D/AndroidRuntime(645): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
05-15 05:10:08.252: D/AndroidRuntime(645): CheckJNI is ON
05-15 05:10:09.132: D/AndroidRuntime(645): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
05-15 05:10:09.161: I/ActivityManager(73): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=soleimannezhad.android.wCFProvinceCity/.Sohsession13WCFProvinceCityActivity} from pid 645
05-15 05:10:09.171: W/WindowManager(73): Failure taking screenshot for (180x300) to layer 21005
05-15 05:10:09.211: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(73): setKernelCountSet(10047, 1) failed with errno -2
05-15 05:10:09.221: D/AndroidRuntime(645): Shutting down VM
05-15 05:10:09.241: D/dalvikvm(645): GC_CONCURRENT freed 102K, 77% free 483K/2048K, paused 2ms+1ms
05-15 05:10:09.241: D/dalvikvm(645): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
05-15 05:10:09.271: I/AndroidRuntime(645): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
05-15 05:10:09.751: V/PhoneStatusBar(141): setLightsOn(true)
05-15 05:10:10.191: V/PhoneStatusBar(141): setLightsOn(true)
05-15 05:10:10.321: I/ActivityManager(73): Displayed soleimannezhad.android.wCFProvinceCity/.Sohsession13WCFProvinceCityActivity: +1s115ms
05-15 05:10:10.631: D/dalvikvm(73): GC_CONCURRENT freed 489K, 6% free 12719K/13447K, paused 5ms+54ms
05-15 05:10:10.782: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(73): setKernelCountSet(10004, 0) failed with errno -2
```

Comment: post your logcat error i need some information about the issue

Comment: I've edited my question and added the logcat

Comment: it's not display any soap related error for varify soap service you can check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20757728/org-ksoap2-serialization-soapserializationenvelope/20760839#20760839

Comment: you are supposed to do network operation in a thread. also check the url `http://localhost:1543/Service1.asmx` that could be a problem

Comment: @ShadiS Your problem could well be what squonk commented on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23709592/null-pointer-exception-on-json-getstring-jsonobject. Also note network operation on a thread not the ui thread

Answer (score 2):

See the image here

[image]

**SOAP_ACTION** : It is your NAMESPACE/METHOD_NAME e.g. "http://ws.android4.com"

**METHOD_NAME** : It's the name of the Method e.g : "sayHello"

**NAMESPACE** : It's your NameSapce e.g: "http://ws.android4.com"

For an **example webservice** see this [webservice of w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?op=CelsiusToFahrenheit)

Here,

METHOD_NAME:`CelsiusToFahrenheit`

SOAPAction: `http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/CelsiusToFahrenheit`

NAMESPACE: `http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/`

**Add Internet permission to Androidanifest.xml file**.

Comment: Thanks @Lal,I have tried this example of http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/ before,but when I try to connect to a web service which is hosted on my localhost I receive the mentioned exception an I can not connect the app to web service!!

Comment: I've tried this ip but again I get the followin exception                                                     "e.getMessage()" expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope (position:START_TAG <HTML>@2:7 in java.io.InputStreamReader@41387778)

Comment: Check if the solutions in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14908145/3168859) are done

Comment: Try adding the answer in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15765386/3168859) in your onCreate(),just to check if that works...

Comment: ALso see this [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/88b6e5/how-to-call-web-service-in-android-using-soap/) for a good tutorial for webservices..Check if that works...

Comment: StrictMode.ThreadPolicy cannot be resolved!!how should I handle it?

Comment: what is your build target???make sure your build target is at least API level 9 (Android 2.3.1).

Comment: I've changed the build target and now there isn't any problem with the namespace of StrictMode.ThreadPolicy   but again I receive  expected: START_TAG {schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope}Envelope (position:START_TAG <HTML>@2:7 in java.io.InputStreamReader@41387778)

Comment: Did you see the link of that tutorial????and try to connect to the w3schools webservice in your code...

Comment: Yes of course ,I had used this tutorial for my first sample app,and it works perfectly, there is something wrong with using the local service hosted on my pc!!!

Comment: yes..i think so, if that example works perfectly...did you try using 10.0.2.2:portnumber to connect to the webservice in localhost???

Comment: @ShadiS I just found out that we can access the webservice in localhost through android by connecting it using the local ip of the system in which you are running the webservice..try it..

Answer (score 2):

Are you debuggin your app from android Emulator? If so, you should start your URL with "http:// 10.0.2.2" so that the emulator can connect to your local web service...

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.WSTest;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;

import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;

import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;

import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.EditText;

import android.widget.Toast;

//import android.widget.SlidingDrawer;;

public class WSTestActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://MVIndia.com/AddActivity";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "AddActivity";
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://MVIndia.com/";
    private static final String URL = "http://10.0.2.2/SAP/Service.asmx";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //final SlidingDrawer txt1 = (SlidingDrawer) findViewById(R.id.Spinner1);
        //final SlidingDrawer txt2 = (SlidingDrawer) findViewById(R.id.Spinner2);
        final EditText txt3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        final EditText txt4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        final EditText txt5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
        final EditText txt6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
        final EditText txt7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);
        final EditText txt8 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText8);
        //final SlidingDrawer txt9 = (SlidingDrawer) findViewById(R.id.Spinner3);
        final EditText txt10 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText10);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnActivity);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
                SoapObject req_AddActivity = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
                req_AddActivity.addProperty("strActivity", "");
                req_AddActivity.addProperty("strActivityType", "");
                req_AddActivity.addProperty("strAssignedTo", txt3.getText().toString());
                req_AddActivity.addProperty("strBPCode", txt4.getText().toString());
                req_AddActivity.addProperty("strBPName", txt5.getText().toString());
                req_AddActivity.addProperty("strActivityDate", txt6.getText().toString());
                req_AddActivity.addProperty("strContactPerson", txt7.getText().toString());
                req_AddActivity.addProperty("strEndDate", txt8.getText().toString());
                req_AddActivity.addProperty("strProgress", "");
                req_AddActivity.addProperty("strRemarks", txt10.getText().toString());

                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envelope.dotNet = true; 
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(req_AddActivity);
                HttpTransportSE  androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE (URL);      
                try {
                    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                    Object result = envelope.getResponse();
                    //if (result.toString()=="True")
                    //{
                        //Toast.makeText(WSTestActivity.this, "Activity added Successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                    //}
                   Toast.makeText(WSTestActivity.this, result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
                    //((TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblStatus)).setText(result.toString());
                } catch(Exception E) {
                    Toast.makeText(WSTestActivity.this, E.getClass().getName() + ": " + E.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                    //((TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblStatus)).setText("ERROR:" + E.getClass().getName() + ": " + E.getMessage());
                }
                //Toast.makeText(WSTestActivity.this, "Caught", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Try this It's working on my local machine. The Webservice returns true if the activity is added successfully. I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'll throw my fix out there... I've run into this several times, and everytime in the past it was the action or the method or the url.  However, this time it was the URL in a weird way...

I'm going through some proxy for a current project.  For some reason, the URL is case sensitive.

https://abc.gov/webservice/webservice.asmx works

https://abc.gov/WEBSERVICE/webservice.asmx DOES NOT work

Hope this helps some.

Answer (score -1):

This error comes when you have not provided the correct URL. Please check URL, Method Name and Soap Action of the web service where you have hosted your web service. It is a good practice to use background services like AsyncTask to call webservices.

Comment: I know that there is a problem with my URL but I can not find it,according to the provided information in my question would you please mention all the Correct URL, Method Name and Soap Action and namepsace for me?I have to use ksoap.

Comment: You should ask the one who has written webservice for correct URL, method name etc.