# Null Pointer exception on JSON.getString JSONObject

Tags: android, json

I am trying to get the username from a database using PHP on android. I have it set up on my localhost. the output on localhost is: `[{"id":"1","username":"Josh","password":"pass"}]`

The PHP is:

```
<?php
$con = $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("natter", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $output[] = $row;
}

print(json_encode($output));

mysql_close($con);
```

The java is:

```
public void setTextToTextView(JSONArray jsonArray) {
    String s = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject json = null;

        try {
            json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            s = s + "Username : " + json.getString("username");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
    status.setText(s);
}
```

and the LOGCAT:

```
05-17 05:09:49.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1846): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-17 05:09:49.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1846): Process: me.docci.natter, PID: 1846
05-17 05:09:49.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1846): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-17 05:09:49.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1846):     at me.docci.natter.Login.setTextToTextView(Login.java:75)
05-17 05:09:49.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1846):     at me.docci.natter.Login$CheckUser.onPostExecute(Login.java:97)
05-17 05:09:49.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1846):     at me.docci.natter.Login$CheckUser.onPostExecute(Login.java:1)
05-17 05:09:49.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1846):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
05-17 05:09:49.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1846):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
05-17 05:09:49.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1846):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
05-17 05:09:49.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1846):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-17 05:09:49.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1846):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-17 05:09:49.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1846):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-17 05:09:49.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1846):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-17 05:09:49.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1846):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-17 05:09:49.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1846):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-17 05:09:49.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1846):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-17 05:09:49.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1846):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have not dealt with JSON before, I used this tutorial to get this code:

[youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Soj22OMc98)

Any ideas?

** UPDATE **
Apparently it is giving null in the jsonArray:

here is the code

```
public JSONArray getUserInfo() {
    String URL = "http://localhost/natter/index.php";

    HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JSONArray jsonArray = null;

    if(httpEntity != null) {
        try {
            String entityResponse = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

            Log.e("Entity Response : ", entityResponse);

            jsonArray = new JSONArray(entityResponse);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return jsonArray;
}
```

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {`

Comment: @user3241507 `jsonArray` is **null** . Before using `jsonArray.length()` print `jsonArray`.

Comment: `jsonArray` is null and you are calling `length()` on null

Comment: I've rarely used PHP but does this line make sense? `$con = $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");`. It's the `$con = $con =` bit that's confusing me.

Comment: @Squonk its what the tutorial said, once this works, I will fix things like that

Comment: Does this line log something that looks like JSON? `Log.e("Entity Response : ", entityResponse);`

Comment: Also, this worries me. `String URL = "http://localhost/natter/index.php";`. Are you testing this on an emulator or real device and where exactly is your PHP code hosted?

Comment: emulator, that is the exact domain to the php code. but it seems to be refusing access? @Squonk

Comment: OK, `localhost` on an emulator refers to the emulated device's own loopback (localhost) address and not the one of the PC the emulator is running on. Change the url to `String URL = "http://10.0.2.2/natter/index.php";`. The IP address `10.0.2.2` on an emulator is routed through to the PC's loopback address.

Comment: @Squonk Now it says that the JSONObject cannot be JSONArray

Comment: @user3241507 : That warrants a separate question. Now you have the network sorted, create a new question showing your JSON being returned from your PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Squonk, I did not know that `localhost` was pointing to `localhost` on the emulator / device. So I changed the URL link to `String URL = "http://10.0.2.2/natter/index.php";` and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure but i idea that your code should be like this.

```
public void setTextToTextView(JSONArray jsonArray) {
    String s = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

        try {
            json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            s = s + "Username : " + json.getString("username");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
    status.setText(s);
}
```

Please try this.